# Is the grammatical construction of this sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I read a sentence in The Hindu which was

Does he regard only Hindus as "the people of India" to the exclusion of other communities?

I think it's fine until India. But the next part "to the exclusion of other communities" does not seem to make much sense to me.
Is this grammatical construction right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example sentence appears to be talking about [Hindu nationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindutva), and how many of its proponents try to exclude (sometimes violently) other ethnic and religious groups from citizenship/political rights in the country. The "exclusion" they are talking about is non-Hindu people being excluded from politics, business, public life, etc.

The phrase "[to the exclusion of](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-the-exclusion-of)" is indeed grammatically correct, and in this case is being used to ask whether the subject of the sentence  excludes everyone other than Hindus from his definition of "the people of India". There are similar constructions that are commonly used with other words besides *"exclusion"*, for instance: *"to the dismay of"*, "*to the astonishment of*", "*to the detriment of*", etc